# What's the best way to annotate this ggplot2 plot? [R]

Tags: r, annotations, plot, ggplot2

Here's a plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = hp, group = factor(am), color = factor(am))) +
    stat_smooth(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", geom = "pointrange") +
    stat_smooth(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", geom = "line") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 130, color = "red") +
    annotate("text", label = "130 hp", x = .22, y = 135, size = 4)
```

I've been experimenting with labeling the geom_hline in a few different ways, each of which does something I want but has a problem that the other methods don't have. `annotate()`, used above, is nice - the text is resizeable, black, and easy to position.  But it can only be placed within the plot itself, not outside the plot like the axis labels. It also makes an "a" appear in the legend, which I can't dismiss with `legend = FALSE`.

`legend = FALSE` works with `geom_text`, but I can't get geom_text to just be black - it seems to be getting tangled up in the line colorings.

`grid.text` lets me put the text anywhere I want, but I can't seem to resize it.

I can definitely accept the text being inside of the plot area, but I'd like to keep the legend clean.

Comment: You can use `gpar` to set the fontsize in `grid.text()`: `grid.text("TEXT", x=..., y=..., gp=gpar(fontsize=20, col="grey"))`

Comment: The latest version of ggplot2 have `legend = F` for annotate by default.  Are you using an older version?

Comment: Ah - I was.  IT blocks me from accessing CRAN via R, so I have to pull the .zips manually - keeps me from updating as often as I should.  Thanks, Hadley.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aesthetics specified in the initial ggplot() call are propagated down through all of the geoms.  But if you don't like it you can specify aesthetics in any layer instead.

So, to prevent geom_text from inheriting the color aesthetic, simply remove "color" from the aes() of your ggplot() call and include a call to aes(color=factor(am)) within your two stat_smooth() calls.

Comment: That makes sense.  I think I had tried to override the color from within the annotate, but just specifying it within the geoms that use it seems more appropriate.  Thanks.

Comment: NB: This answer is obsoleted by latest versions of ggplot2.  See Hadley's comment following the question.

Answer (score 2):

To make it plot like the axis labels, make it an axis label:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = hp, group = factor(am), color = factor(am))) +
    stat_smooth(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", geom = "pointrange") +
    stat_smooth(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", geom = "line") +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 130, color = "red") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks =  c(0, 50, 100, 130, seq(150, 400, 50)))
```

Comment: is there a need for this bit? group = factor(am) inside aes()

Comment: @MartínBel Seems to be - I get an error when I run it without that mapping.  I think `stat_smooth` needs an explicit grouping variable for cases like this. `ggplot2` has changed a lot in the intervening three years, though.